# Webview not firing javascript validations in xamarin forms

Tags: javascript, xamarin, webview

In xamarin mobile app i am rendering my web page in web view. Java script functions are not getting called.

Numeric validations not firing on input

Comment: Can you go through this https://geeks.ms/xamarinteam/2019/02/28/interact-with-javascript-from-c-using-xamarin-forms/

Comment: My web page is loading properly but i have controls on that page such as inputs and i have added validations on that to check only numeric should enter. That events are not firing

Comment: Is it working on your mobile browser?

Comment: No not working in mobile browser as well

Comment: Then it is not the problem of webview..You need to fix it on web page